# How to select array elements in a given range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with let's say, 500 elements. I know I can select the first 100 by doing `.first(100)`, my question is how do I select elements from 100 to 200?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a part of an array in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695290/returning-a-part-of-an-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use ranges in the array subscript:

```
arr[100..200]
```

Comment: You can also do negative ranges as well: arr[100..-50] would get the 100th element through the 450th element, in the case of a 500 element array.

Comment: Note that in ruby a range with two dots `..` represents a range _inclusive_ of the last number, and three dots `...` is _exclusive_.   So `(1..4)` is 1,2,3,4 while `(1...4)` is 1,2,3

Comment: What about `arr[1..]`? This also worked for me to select from the index 1 to the last index but I do not know whether that is correct or not. Because then `RuboCop` warns me on `RubyMine`.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it like this:

```
array[100..200] # returns the elements in range 100..200
# or
array[100,100] # returns 100 elements from position 100
```

[More Information](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002160)

Comment: Interesting answer, for second point using two different numbers would fit better:  array[100,200] # returns 200 elements from position 100

Answer (score 14):

dvcolgan’s answer is right, but it sounds like you might be trying to break your array into groups of 100. If that’s the case, there’s a convenient built-in method for that:

```
nums = (1..500).to_a

nums.each_slice(100) do |slice|
  puts slice.size
end

# => 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sample_array = (1..500).to_a
elements_100_to_200 = sample_array[100..200]
```

You can pass a range as index to an array and get a subarray with the queried elements from that subrange.

Answer (score -4):

```
new_array = old_array.first(200) - old_array.first(100)
```

Comment: That makes sense :). I was wondering if there was a method for this

Comment: That one creates two temporary arrays and then does a set difference... not space and time efficient, I think.

Comment: your right. I'm on a win box and don't have ruby on it so I couldn't try other solutions in irb. I also thought about array.find(100..200) but I don't know if it accepts ranges. Try it out.