# Deleting contents of file after a specific line in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

Probably a simple question, but I need to delete the contents of a file after a specific line number? So I wan't to keep the first e.g 5 lines and delete the rest of the contents of a file. I have been searching for a while and can't find a way to do this, I am an iOS developer so Ruby is not a language I am very familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any methods to delete from a file so my first thought was to read the file and then write back to it. Something like this:

```
path = '/path/to/thefile'
start_line = 0
end_line = 4
File.write(path, File.readlines(path)[start_line..end_line].join)
```

`File#readlines` reads the file and returns an array of strings, where each element is one line of the file. You can then use the [subscript operator with a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525351) for the lines you want

This isn't going to be very memory efficient for large files, so you may want to optimise if that's something you'll be doing.

Answer (score 5):

That is called [truncate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-i-truncate). The truncate method needs the byte position after which everything gets cut off - and the `File.pos` method delivers just that:

```
File.open("test.csv", "r+") do |f|
  f.each_line.take(5)
  f.truncate( f.pos )
end
```

The "r+" mode from File.open is read and write, without truncating existing files to zero size, like "w+" would.

The block form of File.open ensures that the file is closed when the block ends.