# How to split a range into N parts

Tags: ruby, hash, split, range, slice

I am wondering how to split a range into N parts in ruby, While adding them to a hash with a zero based value for each range generated.

For example:

```
range = 1..60
p split(range, 4)
#=> {1..15 => 0, 16..30 => 1, 31..45 => 2, 46..60 => 3}
```

I've read [How to return a part of an array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695290/how-to-return-a-part-of-an-array-in-ruby) for how to slice a range into an array, and a few others on how to convert the slices back into ranges, but I can't quite seem to piece all the pieces together to create the method I want.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

```
range = 1..60

range.each_slice(range.last/4).with_index.with_object({}) { |(a,i),h|
  h[a.first..a.last]=i }
  #=> {1..15=>0, 16..30=>1, 31..45=>2, 46..60=>3}
```

The steps are as follows:

```
enum0 = range.each_slice(range.last/4)
  #=> range.each_slice(60/4)
  #   #<Enumerator: 1..60:each_slice(15)>
```

You can convert this enumerator to an array to see the (4) elements it will generate and pass to `each_with_index`:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  #    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
  #    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
  #    [46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]] 

enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 1..60:each_slice(15)>:with_index>
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 0],
  #    [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], 1],
  #    [[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], 2],
  #    [[46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], 3]] 

enum2 = enum1.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 1..60:each_slice(15)>
  #     :with_index>:with_object({})>
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 0], {}],
  #    [[[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], 1], {}],
  #    [[[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], 2], {}],
  #    [[[46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], 3], {}]]
```

Carefully examine the return values for the calculations of `enum1` and `enum2`. You might want to think of them as "compound" enumerators. The second and last element of each of `enum2`'s four arrays is the empty hash that is represented by the block variable `h`. That hash will be constructed in subsequent calculations.

```
enum2.each { |(a,i),h| h[a.first..a.last]=i }
  #=> {1..15=>0, 16..30=>1, 31..45=>2, 46..60=>3}
```

The first element of `enum2` that is passed by `each` to the block (before `enum.each...` is executed) is

```
arr = enum2.next
  #=>[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 0], {}]
```

The block variables are assigned to the elements of `arr` using *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*)

```
(a,i),h = arr
  #=> [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 0], {}] 
a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
i #=> 0 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is therefore

```
h[a.first..a.last]=i 
  #=> h[1..15] = 0
```

Now

```
h #=> {1..15=>0}
```

The calculations are similar for each of the other 3 elements generated by `enum2`.

The expression

```
enum2.each { |(a,i),h| h[(a.first..a.last)]=i }
```

could alternatively be written

```
enum2.each { |((f,*_,l),i),h| h[(f..l)]=i }
```

Comment: or `.each_slice(15).map.with_index { |d, i| { (d.first..d.last) => i } }` may be more readable

Comment: @llya, a hash is desired, not an array of hashes, each having one key-value pair. Your suggestion to pass the range is a good one, however. I'll incorporate it into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately on my machine `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]` your code returns `{[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]=>0, [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]=>1, [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]=>2, [46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]=>3}` rather than `{1..15=>0, 16..30=>1, 31..45=>2, 46..60=>3} ` was there a slight over sight somewhere? If not how can I detect if a single integer falls between the keys range and return its value. Thanks again.

Comment: Continuation: Before I was using `hash.detect {|k,v| k === 4}.last` to return the value of the range where 4 falls into. This will no longer work as rather than ranges the hash is of type `array=>integer` rather than `range=>integer`. Is there another way to solve this part of the problem? Edit: `hash.detect {|k,v| k.include?(4)}.last` works for now. Thanks again.

Comment: randy, sorry for the inconvenience. I rolled back to my original answer, which I believe is correct. I had made a change that I thought would simplify, but did not test it throughly enough to see that it was wrong. I will add the explanation back in.