# How to enter data into a new array

Tags: ruby

Good morning people. I'm new to Rails and I'm using google translate to post here.

I have an `array`, and I would like to take a certain amount of values from the array, and put them in a new `array1`, for example, the first 7 numbers, and then the next 7 numbers in the second array:

```rb
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
array2 = []    
array3 = []

array = [15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]    
array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]   
array3 = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695290/how-to-return-a-part-of-an-array-in-ruby

Comment: https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/enumerable#method-i-each_cons might also be of some help.

Comment: May I ask, _why_ you want to move some elements to other arrays? Depending on your use case, there might be a better solution than creating a bunch of numbered variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to do that.

**Use [Array#slice!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21)**

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
         16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
         29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

```
array2 = array.slice!(0,7)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array3 = array.slice!(0,7)
  #=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Now,

```
array
  #=> [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  #    28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

If `array` is not to be mutated use [Array#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) and add an additional variable (say, `array1`).

```
array2 = array.slice(0..6)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array3 = array.slice(7..13)
  #=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
array1 = array.slice(14..)
  #=> [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  #    28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

**Use [Enumerable#slice_before](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before)**

```
i = 0
array2, array3, array = array.slice_before { [8, 15].include?(i += 1) }.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  #    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
  #    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  #     28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

Now,

```
array2
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array3
  #=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
array
  #=> [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  #    28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
```

If `array` is not to be mutated replace `array` with `array1` on the left side of the equals sign.

**Partition indices and use [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at)**

```
array2, array3, array = [[*0..6], [*7..13], [*14..(array.size-1)]].
  map { |a| array.values_at(*a) }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  #    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
  #    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
  #     28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

If `array` is not to be mutated replace `array` with `array1` on the left side of the equals sign.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Ruby [shift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-shift) Array method to accomplish this:

```rb
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
array2 = array.shift(7) # array2 is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array3 = array.shift(7) # array3 is now [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Note that the `shift` method edits your original array as well.

By the way, this is pure Ruby (the programming language), no Rails (the framework) here! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `each_slice` here:

```rb
res = array.each_slice(7).to_a
```

And you will get array with subarrays length 7 each. Last element will have remaining:

```rb
# outputs below
[
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
   [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
   [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
   [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
   [36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
]
```

And then you can use `each` to go through elements

```rb
res.each { |subarray| # do with subarray what you need }
```

Or you can get any element you want by using these methods:

```rb
first_subarray = res.first
second_subarray = res.second
last_subarray = res.last

# or by index

third_subarray = res[2]
```

And key thing here that your initial `array` won't be reflected